# How to start full desktop in my own Winlogon shell application?

Tags: c#, windows, winlogon

In Windows 10, I replace explorer.exe to my own AppLauncher.exe in registery:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /f /v shell /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Program Files\AppLauncher\AppLauncher.exe"
```

And I need to return to full desktop in my C# code:

```
            Process newProc = new Process();
            newProc.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer.exe";
            newProc.Start();
```

But after explorer.exe is started, only file management window appears without taskbar.
How can I return back to a whole desktop in my code?

Comment: Why are you doing this?  I suspect you are having problems because of how you are doing it, and there may be a better way, if we knew why you wanted to replace the shell

Comment: Like kiosk mode, we want to start an application defined in our code.